# Renaming multiple files using list of files

Tags: bash, file, file-rename

In bash how would I rename multiple files using names from a text file, I have a directory with multiple .mp3 files: `1.mp3. 2.mp3, 3.mp3, 4.mp3` etc...
and a text file: names.txt with: 
`song1.mp3 
song2.mp3
song3.mp3`
etc..

first line in the text file will correspond to the first line of the file , second line to the second line etc. I have found a few ways to do it in python, but would like to learn how to accomplish this in bash, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files in your directory have names, like `1.mp3`, that contain no tabs or newlines, then the following will work:

```
printf "%s\n" *.mp3 | paste - file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new; do mv "$old" "$new"; done
```

This will work even in the new file names contain blanks, like `Joe's "favorite" song.mp3`.

#### How it works

The printf statement writes each mp3 file name, one per line:

```
$ printf "%s\n" *.mp3
1.mp3
2.mp3
3.mp3
```

The paste command combines the old file names and the new, separating them by a tab:

```
$ printf "%s\n" *.mp3 | paste - file2
1.mp3   song1.mp3
2.mp3   song2.mp3
3.mp3   song3.mp3
```

The read command, `IFS=$'\t' read -r old new`, reads the old and new file names into the shell variables `old` and `new`.

The mv command, `mv "$old" "$new"`, renames the files.

#### Multiple line version

If you like your code spread over multiple lines:

```
printf "%s\n" *.mp3 | paste - file | while IFS=$'\t' read -r old new
do
    mv "$old" "$new"
done
```

Comment: thank you! works great, starting to like bash more than python, but higher learning curve!

Comment: I am also a python enthusiast.  Python and bash each have their own domain.